# Unable to mount samba share

Tags: linux, centos, samba, mount, cifs

I'm using CentOS 5 and I'm trying to mount a share, but I continuously receive the same error.

mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system

mount error(19): No such device

I have samba installed and all of my credentials are correct. I've checked online and I'm still unable to find the problem.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have CIFS utilities installed?

Comment: I was told it was installed already. But upon trying to install cifs-utils, I receive an error that it conflicts with file from package samba client.

Comment: update your system reboot and tell us how it it goes ...

Comment: I'm still having the same issue

Comment: Also make sure that in addition to samba, both cifs-mount, and pam-cifs are all installed, then reboot.